# How to Catch MySql Insert Exception :"1062 (23000): Duplicate entry" while catching other exceptions Python 3?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, exception

I am trying to catch and count the duplicate entry exception :

```
1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '' for key 'tabale.item_UNIQUE'
```

Here is the code that will generate the duplicate Item exception:

```
stmt='INSERT INTO table.items(item) VALUES("iteratorI");'
    try:
        mc.execute(stmt)
        conn.commit()
    except pymysql.IntegrityError as e:
        duplicateCounter=duplicateCounter+1
    except Exception as ee:
        otherErrors=otherErrors+1
```

I would like to be able to count duplicate item entry exceptions separately to keeping the count of other exceptions.

I want to make sure the exception that I am counting is about the duplicate entry and nothing else.
The other issue is that currently duplicateCounter is ending up being zero although I am getting at least 10 1062 exceptions which are counted in  otherErrors

Comment: Have you tried using `sys.exc_info()` to determine the exact `Exception` being caught? https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info Or even `print(type(ee))`.

Comment: I just did and this actually solves my problem, although @booboo answer fixed it earlier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't really stated what your concern is. Is it that you are worried that the `pymysql.IntegrityError` exception might be caused by something other than a duplicate key error? If that is the issue, you can check that the error code associated with the exception is 1062 (DUP_ENTRY) as follows:

```
stmt = 'INSERT INTO table.items(item) VALUES("iteratorI");'
try:
    mc.execute(stmt)
    conn.commit()
except pymysql.IntegrityError as e:
    if e.args[0] == 1062:
        duplicateCounter += 1
except Exception as ee:
    otherErrors += 1
```

If you do not want to hard-code the value `1062`, you could ...

```
from pymysql.constants.ER import DUP_ENTRY
```

... and then compare `e.args[0]` with `DUP_ENTRY`. But you would then be substituting one coding dependency for another.

Comment: Last part of my question was not committed correctly I just edited my questions thanks for pointing out

Comment: is 1062 error code reserved only for dup entery mysql?

Comment: According to the `pymysql` source (file err.py) only `DUP_ERR` equates to 1062.

Comment: And how do you know you are getting 10 1062 errors? This seems questionable.

Comment: I am purposefully inserting items into the DB that are already there, so the exception I am getting is supposed to be 1062

Comment: Perhaps you could update your post with a *complete* yet [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates this.